# Debug Excel Add-In using VS Code without MicrosoftEdgeWebView2 installed

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, office-js, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to migrate my dev env to VSCode and so far I can't get it to work if I have `MicrosoftEdgeWebView2` installed.

I've installed the "Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger" which I think is what I need to use. It shows deprecated/abandonded but its also the top result in Google for debugging Add-Ins by MSFT... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension

Here is my `tasks.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start:desktop -- --app excel",
      "presentation": {
        "clear": true,
        "panel": "dedicated",
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Stop Debug",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "stop",
      "presentation": {
        "clear": true,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
  ]
}
```

and `launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Chromium)",
      "type": "msedge",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
    },
    {
      //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium#appendix-b
      "name": "Excel PWA Desktop (Edge Chromium)",
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "request": "attach",
      "useWebView": true,
      "port": 9229,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
   },
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Legacy)",
      "type": "office-addin",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/index.html?_host_Info=Excel$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
      "port": 9229,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
    },
  ]
}
```

Note: Often online they show port `9222` but I found that at least when I switched to `9229` it didn't start saying `Edge Instance: []` repeatedly, but didn't work, I've tried both.

Also note, I've switched to `index.html`, but that shouldn't matter as long as its correct..

I've tried all variations of the below on both ports:

```
npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml edge
npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml edge-chromium
npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml edge-legacy
npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml ie
npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml default
```

Any ideas how to debug an Excel Office-JS Add-In without having `MicrosoftEdgeWebView2` installed?

I did get it to work w/ my manifest when I had MicrosoftEdgeWebView2 installed so I know my manifest/webserver etc is working and setup correctly.

Comment: On a side note, should I be using `pwa-msedge` or `msedge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in essence, when I uninstall MicrosoftEdgeWebView2 it forces the app to use IE as the rendering engine.

There isn't any official VSCode Extension for debugging IE.

The best I could get was automatically opening F12 or IEChooser.exe after launching Excel/Webserver etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-tools-ie